# CPAN download failing

Tags: perl

Has anyone noticed a serious problem with CPAN downloads?
All of the download links seem to be iunable to resolve www.cpan.org,
but the directory structure inside CPAN doesn't allow any simple swapping to search.cpan.org.
Has anyone found a fix?

Tried to use metacpan.org:

wget http://metacpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MP/MPIOTR/Text-Iconv-1.7.tar.gz

Result:

--2013-06-15 16:00:17--  https://metacpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MP/MPIOTR/Text-Iconv-1.7.tar.gz
Connecting to metacpan.org|46.43.35.68|:443... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name “cpan.metacpan.org” doesn’t match requested host name “metacpan.org”.
To connect to metacpan.org insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.

Tried without certificate: page not found.

What is happening in CPAN?

Comment: Try https://metacpan.org/ instead, search.cpan.org seems broken. You can do something like this : `cpan https://metacpan.org/path/to/Module.pm`

Comment: @sputnick, there were dozens of questions associated with the cpan command, and it never terminated. How do you get past that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://search.cpan.org seems temporarily broken. You can use https://metacpan.org instead. For the certificates, you can bypass it by using :

```
export PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME=0
cpan https://metacpan.org/path/to/Module.pm
```

Comment: so I am trying to download "Text-Iconv-1.7". Not sure how to convert it into your form.

Comment: thanks, I was able to use the meta site. The download through HTTP worked OK so I don't need the WGET trickery yet. We will see. Thanks much.

Comment: Is that the `cpan` command you really used, or were you using a different client?