# read data from excel in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read data from excel, i have below code.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use 5.010;
    use feature 'say';
    use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
    use Spreadsheet::Read qw(ReadData);
    my $book = ReadData ('/tmp/simple.xlsx');

    say 'A1: ' . $book->[1]{A1};

    my @row = Spreadsheet::Read::row($book->[1], 1);
    for my $i (0 .. $#row) {
        say 'A' . ($i+1) . ' ' . ($row[$i] // '');
    }

    my @rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows($book->[1]);
    foreach my $i (1 .. scalar @rows) {
        foreach my $j (1 .. scalar @{$rows[$i-1]}) {
        say chr(64+$i) . " $j " . ($rows[$i-1][$j-1] // '');
        }
    }
```

getting the error as:

```
        Can't locate OLE/Storage_Lite.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/local/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 21.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 21.
    Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm line 14.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm line 14.
    Compilation failed in require at read_excel.pl line 6.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at read_excel.pl line 6.
```

I have every related module. but as per error when i am going to download OLE/Storage_Lite.pm from the CPAN, page is going blank, and from metacpan below error is coming.

```
        https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHWARTZ/OLE-Storage-0.386.tar.gz
    Resolving cpan.metacpan.org... 151.101.128.249, 151.101.192.249, 151.101.64.249, ...
    Connecting to cpan.metacpan.org|151.101.128.249|:443... connected.
    ERROR: certificate common name “a.ssl.fastly.net” doesn’t match requested host name “cpan.metacpan.org”.
    To connect to cpan.metacpan.org insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CPAN download failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127374/cpan-download-failing)

Comment: oooh yours `linux OS`?

Comment: @ssr1012: Please don't recommend that people just copy CPAN modules into their library directories. There are [recommended ways](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html) to install modules.

Comment: @DaveCross can you please provide any link which state why this manual way of keeping the .pm file in the directory structure is so not recommended.

Comment: @DaveCross: Apologies.

Comment: @ssr1012 yes it is linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the module tar zip from [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/OLE-Storage_Lite/lib/OLE/Storage_Lite.pm) or [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/OLE::Storage_Lite). Then build the module locally using any make utility(e.g.dmake). You can find more info for building module locally from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory).